# PostgreSQL regular expression

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have a string like 'ABC3245-bG1353BcvG34'. I need to remove the hyphen including all the letters after hyphen.

so the above string should be ABC3245135334

I tried the below code:

```
select substring('ABC3245-bG1353BcvG34' from 1 for (position('-' in 'ABC3245-bG1353BcvG34')-1))||regexp_replace(substring('ABC3245-bG1353BcvG34' from (position('-' in 'ABC3245-bG1353BcvG34') +1) for length('ABC3245-bG1353BcvG34')),'[a-zA-Z]','')
```

but not able to remove letters after the hyphen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to remove the hyphen including all the letters after hyphen.
>
> so the above string (`ABC3245-bG1353BcvG34`) should be `ABC3245135334`

This suggests that all numbers should remain after the hyphen (in their original order). If that's what you want, you cannot do this with a single regex. Assuming you can have only 1 hyphen in your input:

```
SELECT substring(input.value from '^[^-]*') ||
       regexp_replace(substring(input.value from '[^-]*$'), '\D+', '', 'g')
FROM (SELECT 'ABC3245-bG1353BcvG34'::text AS value) AS input
```

If you can have multiple hyphens in your input, please define how to handle characters between hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

#### Fixed version

```
SELECT a[1] || regexp_replace(a[2], '\D', '', 'g')
FROM   string_to_array('ABC3245-bG1353BcvG34', '-') AS a
```

Or, more convenient to deal with a set (like a table):

```
SELECT split_part(str, '-', 1)
    || regexp_replace(split_part(str, '-', 2), '\D', '', 'g')
FROM  (SELECT 'ABC3245-bG1353BcvG34'::text AS str) tbl
```

Removes *all* non-digits after the hyphen. (Assuming there is only *one* hyphen.) Result:

```
ABC3245135334
```

#### First version

Missed that OP wants to remove *all* letters after `-`.

```
SELECT regexp_replace('ABC3245-bG1353BcvG34', '-\D*', '')
```

Result:

```
ABC32451353BcvG34
```

Regex explained:

`-`  .. literal hyphen `-`
`\D` .. [class shorthand for "non-digits".](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE%22)
`*`  .. 0 or more times

Removes the first hyphen and everything that follows until the first digit.

Comment: But, that's not `ABC3245135334` as in the question. *I need to remove the hyphen including all the letters after hyphen.* The question suggests that all numbers should remain after the hyphen (in their original order).

Comment: @pozs: Thanks. I missed the exact requirement in my first approach. Added working variants.

Answer (score 0):

A RegEx that would work:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=-)
```

Do note that this requires the string to actually contain the hyphen. It uses a lookahead to grab a substring of all alphanumeric characters followed by a hyphen.

Comment: this just gives me the string after hyphen. How do i remove only letters this string

Comment: No, this RegEx returns everything before the hyphen assuming your string is exactly `ABC3245-bG1353BcvG34`. Maybe try anchoring it: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=-)`.